# Intellij android resources gen

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-resources

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour from Intellij that I never had before. I don't know if it's related with this new update (14.0.3) or what. So what happens is every time I add a new resource, let's say a new .xml or a new View in a previous .xml file, my R file doesn't get updated, I've to compile the hole project again, otherwise it warns me about not finding that resource. I've tried to delete the gen folder but it doesn't work either and it gets worse, all my R references get mixed up so I end up with CastExceptions and misplaced drawables, the only was is to re-compile again... It never happen to me before.

Anyone experienced this kind of behaviour?

Comment: i use 14.0.3. works fine for me

Comment: This behaviour just started yesterday, I'm not 100% on this, but I think it only happens in a particular branch of my project. Could some of my project properties files got damaged or so? When it happens affects my sub-modules too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've contacted JetBrains support and their response was:

*Andrey Dernov (JetBrains Support)
Feb 16, 11:41
Hello,
There was a bug with Android projects https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135234 . The issue will be fixed in upcoming 14.0.4 update. Or you can use the last EAP build from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP . We are sorry for inconvenience.
JetBrains, Inc 
http://www.jetbrains.com 
"Develop with pleasure!"*

Answer (score 2):

Four Suggestions:
1) Make sure that you are indeed using the latest-greatest `Android SDK Build Tools`.

2) You could probably use `lint` to determine the lint warnings. Go to `File` > `Settings` > and search for lint in the search box. You will find lot of different options in there. Make sure they are checked. I have had some instances when lint would complain that i am using an attribute in the `.xml` that is not supported and that sometimes catches Intellij off guard.

3) Go into the project structure and at the very bottom there should be a tab `Problems`. Make sure that tab is clean. Sometimes if there is an issue with the path while using third party libraries, `R.java` breaks.

4) Make sure you are indeed using the correct api's available for the target/min SDK you specify.

Hope this helps. If you find the solution please update the OP so that it might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Followed your steps everything was ok, If this error shows up again I'll try to see if I can get something out of the log files.

Comment: Did you add/update any .xml file View id or added new .xml files. This happen in this situations where R.id needs to update but it doesn't. My working colleague started to experience this same problem, and I've this issue in other projects too. I'll contact jetbrains.